# Use code from repository that has no setup.py

Tags: python, reference, workflow, setup.py

Is there a best practice for how to use code from a python github repository that is missing its setup.py file?
Since I cannot reference it through my own requirements.txt, may I just copy the code into one of my own files?

Specifically, I want to use the function tile_raster_images(...) from https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials/blob/master/code/utils.py

Comment: It doesn't look like this was meant to be installed. It looks like a repo for a tutorial. I suppose you could just copy the code and fix import errors as they come up but are you sure the licensing of the project allows you to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just paste the code into your own codebase, yes. As long as it was written for the same Python version and you're aware of the needed dependencies (both to third-party libraries and within the same project), you should be golden.

*However*, the project does **not** have a license. Quoting from the [Github Help](https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing/):

> Generally speaking, the absence of a license means that the default copyright laws apply. This means that you retain all rights to your source code and that nobody else may reproduce, distribute, or create derivative works from your work.

Since you don't definitely know what copyright laws apply to the project, you should be cautious to use the code as you might be committing copyright violation. Especially if this is you're planning to use the code in a commercial product, you're on thin ice.

You should contact the owner of the code and ask them to add a license, so that future users can use the code without worries.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the downside of just copying the code.

The code you want to use is from a tutorial. I think it actually aims to be directly used instead of serving as a python package.

So just copy it somewhere in your project. Be aware of the license of the source code if you intend to republish it.